# Google-maps-for-Rails - undefined method `gmaps' for (object) in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

When I run a rake task that involves a model with gmaps4rails enabled I get this error, and if I comment the model so it's not acts_as_gmappable it completes properly.

```
enter code here
troy$ rake populate:scans --trace
** Invoke populate:scans (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute populate:scans
http://goo.gl/fb/977ze
Sat, 16 Jul 2011 19:43:59 GMT
47.676506
-122.121872
91df0f32209c5212XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
rake aborted!

undefined method `gmaps' for #<Scan:0x000001051fb9a8>
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:392:in `method_missing'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:46:in `method_missing'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/gmaps4rails-0.9.1/lib/gmaps4rails/acts_as_gmappable.rb:12:in `process_geocoding'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/validations.rb:212:in `run_validations!'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:67:in `block in run_validations!'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:67:in `run_validations!'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/validations.rb:179:in `valid?'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/validations.rb:55:in `valid?'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/validations.rb:75:in `perform_validations'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `block (2 levels) in save'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:292:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:207:in `transaction'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:290:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `block in save'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:251:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:239:in `save'
/Users/troy/Documents/projects/qrbrowser/lib/tasks/populate.rake:42:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:239:in `block in each'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `upto'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `each'
/Users/troy/Documents/projects/qrbrowser/lib/tasks/populate.rake:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/troy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/troy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => populate:scans
```

Comment: Do you have a 'gmaps' column or method in your model?

Comment: Sorry - email notifications aren't coming from this site - I invited you to a project to see some code - we can post the update here if you get some time to check it out

Comment: Why is this necessary? Is it an incompatibility with Ruby 1.9 or Rails 3? Nice to know the fix, but i'd also like to understand the root cause that necessitated the fix.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
acts_as_gmappable :process_geocoding => false
```

Solution 2:

When you're creating an instance of your model, do:

```
@scan.instance_eval do
  def process_geocoding
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: You are AWESOME!  best gem support I've ever seen - great to be in a community with members like yourself.

Comment: Thank you Troy, believe me I'm far from being the only one ;)